# Is it possible to pass data from your viewcontroller to a viewcontroller inside pod library?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

First of all, i am not asking if its possible to pass data between view controllers. I am specifically asking if there is anyway to pass some values from a viewController thats in my project to a viewController inside a pod library !

The issue i am facing is that, i am using a payment SDK and the SDK doesn't support pay by saved card info. Normally , whenever i invoke a function from the SDK using a delegate in the sdk, a payment view is presented and it accepts inputs and the SDK works with those inputs.

But what i am trying to do is, pass values from saved card data (name number etc) to the viewController thats inside the pod library.

I tried creating a delegate on my class and tried to access it on the pod library viewController and it returned an error saying that it cannot find the item in scope. I tried creating a global variable and that also returned the same error.

So, this is my question. Is there anyway to pass data from my viewController to the viewController thats present in the SDK ?

Comment: i don't it will work this way. i suggest do it with using `UserDefault` or `KeychainAccess` to save data and second time user went card detail that might me check from your side and directly call that pod file with data and one more thing don't store CVV/CVC.

Comment: @jatinfl No im not storing cvv. The api returns me card data in the form of 411*********111 , name , a card token and expiry. The cvv will be entered in real time by the user and then user will be forwarded to 3ds . But the thing is, i dunno how to pass the data from my api to the cardViewController in the pod

Comment: can you share the pod name which will you use. and some portion of your code?so i will guide you

Comment: @jatinfl Its -- pod 'NISdk' -- By default this SDK doesn't support pay by saved cards but i have managed to add functionality to it make sure it works with saved cards. But the only problem im facing is that, i cannot send card data from my project to this pod. ( I managed to get it working by trying with a hard coded saved card data). Its a PAID SDK, so it wont work unless you have private api keys n stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can, although it will be pointless to. Whenever you try to edit a file in the `/Pods` directory, it will warn you with something similar to the following message

[image]

You can press `Unlock` and append your code, or in your case, a delegate. But the next time you run `pod install`, it would override everything you've written.

The real pain starts when collaborating, as the `/Pods` directory does not get pushed into VCS.

Comment: Nope, i wasnt talking about this. I know i can edit it , what i am trying to achieve is to pass some values from my ``viewController`` to a ``viewController`` inside the pod. Whenever i try that, it just gives me unable to find the said item in scope !

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way to this. I made this happen by using `sharedInstance`

This is how i did it, here i created a sharedInstance variable.

```
@objc public final class NISdk: NSObject {
    @objc public static let sharedInstance = NISdk()

//We will write the next function here//
}
```

Then i made a function that accepts parameters

```
@objc public func SavedCardPayment(cardToken : String,expiryMonth : String,
expiryYear : String,cvv : String,cardholderName : String,useSavingCards : Int)
    { // we will write some ways to store the values we just got as parameters// }
```

On this function

```
{
 //You must declare these global variables somewhere inside the pod ! 
        ViewControllerInsidePod.savedCardToken = cardToken
        ViewControllerInsidePod.savedExpiryMonth = expiryMonth
        ViewControllerInsidePod.savedExpiryYear = expiryYear
        ViewControllerInsidePod.savedCvv = cvv
        ViewControllerInsidePod.savedName = cardholderName
}
```

Now all info which user entered on the screen will be passed to SDK and then stored in these global variables (which are only available inside the pod n not in the project). Then i used these values to call a function of the pod from itself.

Now i will go back to my viewController in my project, and then call the function using sharedInstance

```
let sharedSDKInstance = NISdk.sharedInstance
let sharedSDKInstance = NISdk.sharedInstance
        sharedSDKInstance.SavedCardPayment(cardToken : "\(token)",
    expiryMonth : "\(expiryM)",expiryYear : "\(expiryY)",cvv : "\(cvv)",
    cardholderName : "\(name)",useSavingCards : 1)
```

Hope this helps someone, i dunno if this is the right way to do it but this is how i passed data from a viewController that was outside of scope!

**REMEMBER THIS**
Also as @Visal Rajapakse , this will only work as long as you never update that specific pod !