# How to target data from Pod from ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have an Xcode project that I added a pod to and am having some issues targeting the 'Submit' button in the pod. I will also need to get data from the text fields in there to pass to my functions.
I found this article [Is it possible to pass data....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68319361/is-it-possible-to-pass-data-from-your-viewcontroller-to-a-viewcontroller-inside) and it may work but it is a few years old and it seems like xcode and swift change quickly so maybe there is a newer way of doing this?
Originally I had a button in my view controller and @IBOutlet event attached to it and now that I have loaded a pod, I can't figure out how to listen for the that button event so I can run my functions in the View Controller where the pod is loaded.
The pod I am using the SimpleCCForm and it is installed and I am able to load successfully.

Comment: Since a pod is a library, usually source code, the idea of loading it in a view controller isn't easy to visualize.  Can you insert the code that does that into your question?

Comment: @PhilipMills
The pod basically creates a credit card form with input fields and a card image and it can be inserted as a subView into the view controller as follows;

```    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let width = self.view.frame.width
        let simpleCCForm = SimpleCCForm(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 100, width: width - 20, height: 600))
        view.addSubview(simpleCCForm)
    }```